# Can I reliably use the indexes of list generated by python dictionary key method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
mydict = {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
          '2': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
          '3': ['g', 'h', 'i'], 
          '4': ['j', 'k', 'l'], 
          '5': ['m', 'n', 'o']}
```

According to the Python documentation,

> The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the
>   keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order

When I call `mydict.keys()` method, it will give me a list of keys in the `mydict` without any particular order like this:

> ['1', '3', '2', '5', '4']

My Question is does the key list(above) generated by `.keys()` method has the same order everytime I call it? I have tried it using for loop like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    print mydict.keys()
```

It seems to me that the resulting list has always the same order. But I just want to confirm that there is no hidden case that will change the order of output list.

In other word, if i use `mydict.keys()[0]` , will I get the same item every time?

Comment: Wouldn't bet my life on it...

Comment: As long as you don't add elements to the dictionary I think it should be fine. But I let Python experts speak.

Comment: @FelixKling, I think it can also vary from version to version

Comment: I would wager it's in hashmap order, so if you construct the dictionary in exactly the same manner while running on exactly the same interpreter, it will most likely be the same.   Try adding a few thousand items and removing them, I bet the order changes.

Comment: @sshashank124: Possibly. But regardless, if the question boils down to "does `.keys()` return the same list if called twice in a row", I'd say yes. It's not that the elements of the dictionary are stored in an indeterministic way and I think that *reading* the dictionary doesn't impact it's internal storage structure either. Mutating the dictionary can of course change the "order" in which the elements are stored internally.

Comment: The order is definitely not consistent in Python3, so for the sake of future-compatibility, don't rely on it.

Comment: @unutbu: Are you saying that the above code prints the elements in different order in each (some) iterations?

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes; `print(mydict.keys())` may print `dict_keys(['5', '4', '1', '3', '2'])` one time, then `dict_keys(['1', '3', '2', '5', '4'])` the next, for example.

Comment: @unutbu: Mmmh, then I'm really wondering what happens internally.

Comment: So, I guess it's better to call `.keys()` method once and store it in a list and use that list to access the dictionary later on.

Comment: @FelixKling: To be clear, I'm talking about independent runs of the program, *not* multiple calls to `mydict.keys()` within the same python process.

Comment: @unutbu, my Python 3 install (Fedora 18) gives me (in this case) the 1,3,2,5,4 order consistently, 100k checks.  Edit: your most recent comment makes sense, my checks were within the same process.

Comment: @unutbu: Oh, ok... that's what I meant (although that's also good to know).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never rely on ordering when using a dict. Even though you test it 1 billion times and it *looks* homogeneous, there's nothing in the specification that states that it is, and thus there can be some hidden code that says "*every full moon that begins on an even day, change the order*".

If you want to rely on ordering, then use [`OrderedDict` from `collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: +1 for `OrderedDict`. If the spec says "*returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order*", then you write your code to respect that.

Answer (score 2):

> My Question is does the key list(above) generated by .keys() method
>   has the same order everytime I call it?

If there are no intervening modifications to the dictionary, then the order would be the same.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> If `items()`, `keys()`, `values()`, `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and
>   `itervalues()` are called with no intervening modifications to the
>   dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the
>   creation of `(value, key)` pairs using `zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())`. The same relationship holds for the `iterkeys()` and
>   `itervalues()` methods: `pairs = zip(d.itervalues(), d.iterkeys())`
>   provides the same value for pairs. Another way to create the same list
>   is `pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in d.iteritems()]`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot rely on the order.
The reason is that the keys are hashed and placed in a table accordingly. The size of the table is adjusted up whenever the dictionary is 2/3 full (I think this is the number) in order to avoid too many collisions and maintain an O(1) access time, and adjusted down (I think when it is 1/3rd full), to manage memory utilization.

Because it is a hash table, the sequence in which the dictionary is constructed will affect the ordering of the keys.
The hash function may change in future versions...

If you need to use the keys in a reliable order, you could look into **collections OrderedDict**, this might be what you are looking for. [edit: I just noticed you are using python 2.7, OrderedDict is only available in Python 3.+]